# How *exactly* are you supposed to use useContext?

Tags: reactjs

I'm familiar with Redux, but I'm having a hard time grasping the concept of useContext.

I have the following code;

```
export default () => {
    const PlayerStatusContext = React.createContext(null);
    const [playerStatus, setPlayerStatus] = useState({
        playerHealth: 5,
        playerCoins: 0,
        playerMoves: 0,
        currentLevel: 1,
    });
    const usePlayerStatus = () => useContext(PlayerStatusContext);
    return (
            <PlayerStatusContext.Provider value={ playerStatus, setPlayerStatus } >
                 <ChildComponent />
            </PlayerStatusContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

And in the childComponent;

```
export default ({playerStatus, setPlayerStatus}) => {

    return (
        <Wrapper>
            <button onClick={() => {
                console.log(playerStatus)
            }}>Log status</button>

            <button onClick={() => {
                setPlayerStatus({
                    playerHealth: 6,
                    playerCoins: 1,
                    playerMoves: 1,
                    currentLevel: 2,
                })
            }}>Update Test</button>
        </Wrapper>
    )
}
```

Now, I've been told that I shouldn't pass playerStatus and setPlayerStatus directly, and I should wrap them in a handler. How exactly should I go about doing this, and what's the benefit of doing so?

Comment: \*exaclty\* like this: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Sorry, but that doesn't really explain my question/use case.

Comment: The implicit hint was that you needed to [rephrase your question](/help/how-to-ask) instead of using a title that doesn't actually summarize the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ChildComponent` should look like this:

```
const ChildComponent = () => {
    const { playerStatus, setPlayerStatus } = usePlayerStatus();

    return (
        // remaining code
    );
}
```

If you pass the value and the callback through context, you don’t need to pass as props. Alternatively, if you want to pass them explicitly, you can return

```
<ChildComponent
    playerStatus={playerStatus}
    setPlayerStatus={setPlayerStatus}
/>
```

in your parent, but then you don’t need the context.